# Backbone.js - Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'apply'

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am new to Backbone.js. For experimenting / initial development, I had everything on one page in the   tag, but I started separating out the code into a separate .js file. After I did that I get an error coming from the Router.

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'apply'

Here is my Router code:

```
       var AppRouter = new Backbone.Router.extend({
            routes: {
                ":uuid": "details"
            },
            details: function (uuid) {
                // load details
                new DetailView({id: uuid, el: $('#detailView')});
            }
        });

        var appRouter = new AppRouter;
```

I have the Models/Views loaded in a file  tag above, but even if I comment out the file's  tag or empty the file, it still displays thing error.

The line throwing the error is `var appRouter = new AppRouter;`

I'm I doing something wrong with the router code.

Thanks!!
Andrew

Comment: lose the `new` in `var AppRouter = new Backbone.Router.extend({...`

Comment: Change `var AppRouter = new Backbone.Router.extend({` to  `var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({` and change `var appRouter = new AppRouter;` to `var appRouter = new AppRouter();`

Comment: @Andbdrew you are correct! :) I feel a little stupid, it must of creeped in there during the file move.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Remove the `new` in `var AppRouter = new Backbone.Router.extend({...`

Comment: hehe damn easy to miss!